# doAnswer() to modify passed objects is not being called for Void method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Use Case:

I want to call a method of mocked class with list of objects and want to modify passed parameters. It works fine if I work on some method with return type and doesn't work for Void returning methods.

Method to test:

```
 public class TestClass{
                    @Autowired 

                PersistActivity activity;

                public void methodToTest(List<URLObject> urlObjects) {
                            List<URLObject> urlObjects2PerformAction = new ArrayList<URLObject>();

                   for (URLObject urlObject : urlObjects) {
                            // Added this check to make sure, we are not running a previous
                            // activity which is successful.
                            if (urlObject.getRetryCountMap().get(currentActivityName) != null) {
                                    urlObjects2PerformAction.add(urlObject);
                            }
                    }
                    boolean activityStatus = true;
                    try {
                        log.info("Calling activity " + currentActivityName + " with " + urlObjects2PerformAction);
                        activity.doActivity(urlObjects2PerformAction);
                        log.info("UrlObjects are " + urlObjects2PerformAction);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //another set of actions.
                    }
                    for (URLObject urlObject : urlObjects) {
                        if (!urlObject.isActivitySuccessful()) {
                                // If complete call failed or partial data failed, update
                                log.info("Failed for message " + urlObject);
                        } else {
                             log.info("Passed for message " + urlObject);
                        }
                    }//end for
            }//end method
        }//end class
```

In this example, I want to modify urlObjects to populate one of its boolean variable to be true/false.

I have added a `doAnswer()` clause in test case like this:

Test Class:

```
  public class TestMe{
    @Mock
    private PersistActivity activity;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<List<URLObject>> argument;

   @InjectMocks
    private DCUrlPersistor dcUrlPersisor = new DCUrlPersistor();


   @Test
public void runIndividualDeamonWithMultipleMessagesSomeFailing() throws Exception {


    URLObject urlObject1 = getUrlObject(normalizedUrl, normalizedUrl, scraperName);
    URLObject urlObject2 = getUrlObject("test2.com", "test2.com", "gpsUS");


Map<String,Integer> retryCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
retryCountMap.put(PersisterActivitiesEnum.CSI.getName(), 0);

urlObject1.setRetryCountMap(retryCountMap);
urlObject2.setRetryCountMap(retryCountMap);

/**
 * Change argument passed to the method.
 */     
doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) 
      throws Throwable 
    {
        Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();

        if (    arguments != null 
                && 
                arguments.length > 0 
                && 
                arguments[0] != null) 
        {
            List<URLObject> objs = (List<URLObject>) arguments[0];
            Assert.assertNotNull(objs.get(0).getRetryCountMap());
            objs.get(0).setActivitySuccessful(false);
        }
        return null;
    }     
}).when(activity).doActivity(anyList());


doNothing().when(activity).doActivity(Arrays.asList(urlObject1, urlObject2));

/**
 * Call method.
 */
dcUrlPersisor.methodToTest(Arrays.asList(urlObject1, urlObject2));
/**
 * Verify various instances and logs.
 */
verify(activity, times(1)).doActivity(argument.capture());
assertEquals(2, argument.getValue().size());
assertEquals(normalizedUrl, argument.getValue().get(0).getNormalizedURL());     
Assert.assertTrue(logContains("Calling activity csi with "));
//-----This is the part which fails as log never prints this message----//
Assert.assertTrue(logContains("Failed for message"));


    }
}
```

Issue:

If I change the return type of `doActivity` method to be `List<ABC>` than `Void`, then it gets called and works as expected (without changing the test code).

Do we need some changes for void methods? I have already set it to return void in doAnswer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `Activity` look like? Do you get any errors at all? Additionally, your code has a few compilation errors and runtime errors - unless you meant to replace `URLObject` with `ABC` everywhere? Anyway, can you post your actual code please? Thanks.

Comment: If I correct compilation problems and substitute `ABC` for `URLObject` and assume `Activity` has a `void doActivity(List<ABC> abcs)` method, it works for me, i.e. `abc[0].activitySuccessful == false`. Perhaps something else is going on?

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for your time. I might be doing something silly and have added the least amount of code to understand the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the following line:

```
doNothing().when(activity).doActivity(Arrays.asList(urlObject1, urlObject2));
```

To me, it seems a bit contrary to the `doAnswer` set up that precedes it.

Comment: Oops! :( I think it was a copy paste and I din't realize that there are two actions defined!

Answer (score 0):

Change `Void` to `Object` like this.

```
...
doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    ...
```

Comment: Hi David, why should it work? Return type of method is void. Do you expect to return modified object?

Though I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: I changed return type of Answer to Object and it returns null as earlier.

Comment: OK, so maybe your mock object isn't actually getting injected the way you think it is.  Can you post your actual test class, so we can find the bug?  It looks like you've tried to retype it and made a few typos (such as the spelling of InjectMocks), so it's hard to be sure what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I did type it assuming that some high level issues are there. I have added detailed methods.